# Adding Database User when Database in Read Only Mode

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add user to Database ,
But database in Read-Only Mode ,

Here TestDB in read-only Mode ,

```
 USE [TestDB];
             IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = ''' +@username+''')    
     CREATE USER ['+ @username +'] FOR LOGIN ['+ @username +'];     

           END;
```

Comment: Which dbms are yoyu using? That code is product specific.

Comment: If it's in **read-only** mode, you **cannot** add users or modify table data - that's the **WHOLE POINT** of having read-only mode....

Comment: SQL Server 2016